# How do use "Import Range" to call data from one sheet and keep it in another spreadsheet even if its deleted from the original spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, importrange

I have a spreadsheet (SpreadsheetA) that is going to be constantly refreshing. Rows will be added and removed, but I want to use "import range" (or some other method) to store all the rows that are entered into SpreadsheetA in another spreadsheet even if they're removed from SpreadsheetA

I've been researching on this site and on google for hours and haven't found a solution.

Comment: Do you have any code sample? I can suggest to use Apps Script with Google Sheets. If you have a sample code share it to see what you have.

Answer (score 0):

you will need something like this:

```
function tc() {
    var reference = 'sheet1!A2'; 
    var rng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(reference);
    rng.setValue(rng.getValue()+1);
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
    var source = ss.getRange ("Sheet1!A5:H");
    var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    var values = source.getValues().filter(function(e) {return e.some(function(f) {return f})});
destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

anytime cell `sheet1!A2` changes the range `Sheet1!A5:H` gets archived in `Sheet2`

Comment: I don't have any experience with google apps script. Would that be the only way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: yes, the script is the only way how to accomplish your task

Comment: Thanks for your help! Can you explain how the second to last line of the code you wrote is working? I've gained a little bit more experience with apps script but I'm still confused as to what "function(e) {return e.some(function(f) {return f })});" means and what its doing.